# Push notification on ios app with appcenter not succeeded

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, push-notification, testflight, visual-studio-app-center

I generated a cer from keychain on my mac to generate cer as distribution (adhoc + app store).
Then modified the app identifier to get Push Notification feature using the first cer.
Provison profile now as distribution for ios app.
Generated a key to appcenter .p8. and configured my ios app there as production.
In VS I enabled Push Notification on `Entitlements.plist`. ( here I couldn't debug the app on my physical device, I didn't know why?).
Installed the nuget Package and inserted the code having my app secret which provided of appcenter.

```
AppCenter.Start("{Your App Secret}", typeof(Push));
```

Released my app to my developer acc, stared testing using testflight, sent notification but no device received. 
Tried another devices but no action.

Could you help me please; I am so confused.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the settings in the document: [Get Started with Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/xamarin) and [Preparing for Notification Delivery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=windows#preparing-for-notification-delivery).

Comment: Could you include the verbose logs pls? Thanks!